# Обработка строк в pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, анализ-данных, обработка-данных

Есть такой набор данных во фрейме данных:

```
                      0        2        3        5
0     2021-03-23 07:06:27.758  1.19236  1.19237  6
1     2021-03-23 07:06:31.898  1.19237  1.19238  6
2     2021-03-23 07:06:33.196  1.19237  1.19240  4
3     2021-03-23 07:06:33.919  1.19237  1.19238  4
4     2021-03-23 07:06:36.596  1.19237  1.19239  4
```

Задача такая: нужно чтобы брались значения в столбцах 2 и 3, сверялись со значениями в тех-же столбцах выше, и если значения хоть по одному из столбцов изменялось в меньшую сторону, то в столбце 5 менялось на отрицательное значение.

К примеру данных выше:

```
                      0        2        3         5
0     2021-03-23 07:06:27.758  1.19236  1.19237   6
1     2021-03-23 07:06:31.898  1.19237  1.19238   6
2     2021-03-23 07:06:33.196  1.19237  1.19240   4
3     2021-03-23 07:06:33.919  1.19237  1.19238  -4
4     2021-03-23 07:06:36.596  1.19237  1.19239   4
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

попробуйте так:

```
df["5"] = np.where(df["2"].diff().lt(0)|df["3"].diff().lt(0), df["5"]*-1, df["5"])
```

df:

```
                         0        2        3  5
0  2021-03-23 07:06:27.758  1.19236  1.19237  6
1  2021-03-23 07:06:31.898  1.19237  1.19238  6
2  2021-03-23 07:06:33.196  1.19237  1.19240  4
3  2021-03-23 07:06:33.919  1.19237  1.19238 -4
4  2021-03-23 07:06:36.596  1.19237  1.19239  4
```

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо) получилось и работает)

Answer (score 4):

еще одно решение:

```
df.loc[df[["2","3"]].diff().lt(0).any(axis=1), "5"] *= -1
```

результат:

```
In [86]: df
Out[86]:
                         0        2        3  5
0  2021-03-23 07:06:27.758  1.19236  1.19237  6
1  2021-03-23 07:06:31.898  1.19237  1.19238  6
2  2021-03-23 07:06:33.196  1.19237  1.19240  4
3  2021-03-23 07:06:33.919  1.19237  1.19238 -4
4  2021-03-23 07:06:36.596  1.19237  1.19239  4
```